# jmeter: Cookies coming as null when hitting the specific server

Tags: java, cookies, jmeter

I'm using apache jmeter for testing my java application. When I hit the GTM(global traffic manager: this routes the traffic to specific server depending on the load) url https:// on port 443 everything works fine.
When I try to hit the specific server on which the the application is deployed using the url http:// on port 8080, I get 401 unauthorized error because cookies are coming as null in the request.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess what is the problem when you don't provide any code/configuration.

Probably you are running into issue because of `same origin policy` (browser and tools are sending only cookies which belongs to the origin to which you are sending request).

I guess that you are retrieving cookies from `https://someApp.com:443` and try to reuse them with `http://someapp.com:8080`. The problem is, that they are not same origins (port number is treated as part of origin URL).

Check out this links:

- [JMeter Issue with SSO and Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400787/jmeter-issue-with-sso-and-cookies)
- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56358

Answer (score 0):

You could try disabling JMeter cookies checking:

1. Temporarily (once only), via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -JCookieManager.check.cookies=false -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. Permanent, by adding the next line to *user.properties* file (located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you have only 1 [Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager).

> If there is more than one Cookie Manager in the scope of a Sampler,
>   there is currently no way to specify which one is to be used. Also, a
>   cookie stored in one cookie manager is not available to any other
>   manager, so use multiple Cookie Managers with care

Answer (score 0):

In `jmeter.properties` file make the below change and it will fix the issue.

```
CookieManager.delete_null_cookies=false
```